# Add css file in HTML2FPDF

Tags: php, html

Does anyone know how to include CSS files in HTML2FPDF PHP library. I am able to generate a PDF file but style is not including. Currently I am appending the style sheets in the header of HTML string($my_html).

Here is my code.

```
 $pdf = new HTML2FPDF();
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->WriteHTML($my_html);
            $pdf->Output('pdffile_.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Html2fpdf documentantion](http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v4:accueil) i dont found any method to include extra files to the pdf output document, so i think that the best solution is concatenate it to your `$my_html` variable. See:

```
$my_html .= "<style>\n " . file_get_contents('path/to/style.css') . "</style>";

$pdf = new HTML2FPDF();
           $pdf->AddPage();
           $pdf->WriteHTML($my_html);
           $pdf->Output('pdffile_.pdf');
```